# visual studio drawing adornment with lazy update

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I'm making an Visual Studio adornment extension. I want to update adornments if there is no user input at least 2 seconds. So i constructed a worker and tried to remove and add adornment but VS says it can't be updated because non-ui thread had called it. So I waited without thread then my editor goes really laggy (because the ui thread waits)

I want to know if there is a way to update adornments with lazy update.
Drawing adornment is done by calling AddAdornment(), and i can't find how to invoke ui thread to draw.

Below is my code

```
    internal async void OnLayoutChanged(object sender, TextViewLayoutChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Print("OnLayoutChanged Called");

        task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Print("task Started");
            if (e.NewSnapshot != e.OldSnapshot)
            {
                parseStopwatch.Restart();
                shouldParse = true;
            }

            ParseWork(e);
        });
        await task;


    }


    private async void ParseWork(object param)
    {
        var e = (TextViewLayoutChangedEventArgs)param;
        if (e == null)
        {
            shouldParse = false;
            parseStopwatch.Stop();
            CsharpRegionParser.ParseCs(this.view.TextSnapshot);
            DrawRegionBox();
            return;
        }

        while (shouldParse)
        {
            Task.Delay(10);
            if ((shouldParse && parseStopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds > 2000) || parseStopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds > 5000)
            {
                break;
            }

        }
        shouldParse = false;
        parseStopwatch.Stop();
        CsharpRegionParser.ParseCs(this.view.TextSnapshot);
        DrawRequest(e);

        return;

    }
```

Comment: Wait in a background task, Invoke to main thread to update

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why you were down-voted, particularly because this is an interesting problem when dealing with extensions.

So, to your first problem: Visual Studio has the same requirements as WPF (with some added complications due to its COM dependency).  You can't update a UI element when you're not on the Main (UI) thread.  Unfortunately, if you dive right in and approach it using the strategies you'd use for WPF, you'll experience a whole other world of problems (deadlocks, mostly).

First things first, brush up on how to handle switching from background to UI threads in Visual Studio extension land.  I found [Asynchronous and Multithreaded programming within VS using JoinableTaskFactory](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/andrewarnottms/2014/05/07/asynchronous-and-multithreaded-programming-within-vs-using-the-joinabletaskfactory/) to be helpful in explaining.

I had to do something similar with an expensive parsing operation.  It was pretty straight forward.

My parser executes as part of an `IViewModelTagger` instance and uses the following sequence (roughly):

1. It subscribes to the `ITextBuffer.ChangedLowPriority` event with an `async void` event handler.
2. Immediately on fire, it cancels any parsing operation in progress via a `CancellationToken.Cancel()` call.  The cancellation token is passed into everything that supports it (in Roslyn, it's supported everywhere you would want it to be).
3. It begins the parsing operation, but before starting it, I have a `Task.Delay(200, m_cancellationToken)` call.  I 200ms based on my typing speed and the fact that Roslyn's operations have `CancellationToken` overloads for anything expensive (my parsing work is pretty light-weight, too).  YMMV.

I work with WPF components that require the UI thread quite a bit and they're intermingled within the `IViewModelTagger` and the `IWpfTextViewListener`.  They're lightweight enough that I could have skipped async'ing them, but on very large classes they can hang the UI.

To handle this, I did the following:

1. On the TextViewLayoutChanged, I subscribe with an `async void` event handler.
2. I `Task.Run()` the expensive operations first, preventing the UI from being blocked.
3. When I do the final creation of the WPF UI elements and add them as adornments finalization (along with a couple of operations within the SDK that require it), I `await ThreadHelper.JoinableTaskFactory.SwitchToMainThreadAsync()` to get the UI thread.

I mentioned "other SDK operations", that's important.  There are several things you cannot do within the SDK on anything but the Main thread (memory is failing me now, but parts of the TextView in particular will fail, and not consistently, if they're accessed on background threads).

There are more options for executing the work off of the UI thread (Ordinary `Task.Run` works, as well as `ThreadHelper.JoinableTaskFactory.Run`).  The Andrew Arnott post linked earlier in my answer explains all of the choices.  You'll want to understand that fully since there are reasons to use some over others depending on the task.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

`Task.Delay` as used in your code returns a task that completes when you delay. If you call it like that and ignore the result, it didn't do what you thought it did. What you probably meant to is instead of calling Task.Factory.StartNew as you did, you want:

```
var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
Task.Delay(2000, cancellationTokenSource.Token).ContinueWith(() => DoWork(), cancellationTokenSource.Token, TaskScheduler.Current).
```

This says effectively "kick off a timer that'll wait 2 seconds, and then once it completes run the DoWork method on the UI thread. If more typing happens, then you can call cancellationTokenSource.Cancel() and just run again.

Also, I do have to ask about your type "CSharpRegionParser". If you need region information and you're on Visual Studio 2015, then you can get the syntax tree from Roslyn and you should be watching workspace change events rather than hooking LayoutChanged. You're also best off then structuring your system as a tagger/adornment manager pair as it might be clearer to write...it's not clear to me why you'd do parsing logic in LayoutChanged since LayoutChanged is something that happens during visual layout, including scrolling, resizing, etc.

Comment: I tried but I failed. What I needed was a dispatcher.